# Xcode / Cordova build: how to automate the population of "Linked Frameworks and Libraries"

Tags: xcode, cordova

After I `cordova platform rm ios` and `cordova platform add ios`, once I prepare my app I have to go into Xcode and manually relink all of the required frameworks and libraries.

Is there a way to automate this or at the very least, save this list so I can add it easily?

[image: looooong]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't specify frameworks within the [config.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/config_ref_index.md.html).

You *can* specify them within a plugin's [plugin.xml](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/plugin_ref_spec.md.html), 
so one workaround would be to create a barebones dummy plugin consisting of just a plugin.xml with a list of all the frameworks your app needs; something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<plugin
    xmlns="http://apache.org/cordova/ns/plugins/1.0"
    id="my-custom-frameworks-plugin"
    version="0.0.1">

  <engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
  </engines>

  <platform name="ios">
    <framework src="MapKit.framework" />
    <framework src="Social.framework" />
  </platform>
</plugin>
```

You'd then add the plugin to your app using it's local path: `cordova plugin add /path/to/my/plugin`

And then specify it using a `<plugin>` element in your config.xml:

```
<plugin name="my-custom-frameworks-plugin" version="0"/>
```

Each time you remove then add the platform, the plugin will be re-added and the referenced frameworks added to the XCode .plist file.

Alternatively, you could write a custom `after_platform_add` [hook](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/edge/guide_appdev_hooks_index.md.html) to read `<framework>` elements directly from the config.xml and update the .plist file.

Comment: Took me a while to come around and try it, but this definitely works. I guess that proper cordova plugins do this automatically; we had some custom in there as well... Thanks!